# Unable to Locate Package? Repository is added!

Tags: ubuntu, apt, repository, ppa

I'm stuck here.
I'm trying to update java on a corporate machine with strict firewalls.

As such I can't use the ppa command, and added the WebUpd8 repository to my sources list manually:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu trusty main
```

When I run apt-get update:

```
root@graylog:/home/ubuntu# sudo apt-get update | grep -i ppa
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en
```

and then attempt to install...

```
root@graylog:/home/ubuntu# sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package oracle-java8-installer
```

Any ideas? I'm trying to get Java in as a prereq for configuring Graylog.
Thanks.

Comment: We cannot guess which fw restrictions you have, and as such cannot give you the best way you can do it. Getting directly the deb also wont do nay good, as I think the .deb downloads the .tar.gz. Installing the tar.gz will be harder, but thatś what you got.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm a bit of a novice. If the issue is the firewall stopping the download, does it give the "unable to locate package" error? It just doesn't seem as obvious to me as it should...I would expect it to "locate" the package and fail to retrieve it, if that makes sense. I'm not familiar with the different cases when attempting to install via apt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying with the wrong PPA. Please try with this command line,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

and if it cannot pass the firewall, try manually according to the instructions at the following link, the 'Technical details about this PPA',

[Oracle Java (JDK) 8 / 9 Installer PPA](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java)

It works for me (but I have no problems with the firewall). Good luck :-)

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
 Oracle Java (JDK) Installer (automatically downloads and installs Oracle JDK8). There are no actual Java files in this PPA.

Important -> Why Oracle Java 7 And 6 Installers No Longer Work: http://www.webupd8.org/2017/06/why-oracle-java-7-and-6-installers-no.html

Update: Oracle Java 9 has reached end of life: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk9-downloads-3848520.html

The PPA supports Ubuntu 18.04, 17.10, 16.04, 14.04 and 12.04.

More info (and Ubuntu installation instructions):
- for Oracle Java 8: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html

Debian installation instructions:
- Oracle Java 8: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/how-to-install-oracle-java-8-in-debian.html

For Oracle Java 10, see a different PPA: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/04/install-oracle-java-10-in-ubuntu-or.html
 Mer info: https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java
Tryck [RETUR] för att fortsätta eller Ctrl-c för att avbryta tilläggande.

Bra:1 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease
Bra:2 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates InRelease                                  
Bra:3 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-backports InRelease                                
Bra:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mkusb/unstable/ubuntu cosmic InRelease        
Läs:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu cosmic InRelease [15,4 kB]
Läs:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 Packages [1 556 B]
Läs:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu cosmic/main i386 Packages [1 556 B]
Läs:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu cosmic/main Translation-en [928 B]
Läser paketlistor… Färdig
```

Your test via `grep` should output a line like this for the correct PPA to be active,

```
$ sudo apt-get update|grep -i ppa
Bra:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu cosmic InRelease
```

Installing produced the following output for me,

```
$ sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer 
Läser paketlistor… Färdig
Bygger beroendeträd       
Läser tillståndsinformation… Färdig
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gsfonts-x11 java-common oracle-java8-set-default
Föreslagna paket:
  binfmt-support visualvm ttf-baekmuk | ttf-unfonts | ttf-unfonts-core ttf-kochi-gothic | ttf-sazanami-gothic ttf-kochi-mincho | ttf-sazanami-mincho
  ttf-arphic-uming
Följande NYA paket kommer att installeras:
  gsfonts-x11 java-common oracle-java8-installer oracle-java8-set-default
0 att uppgradera, 4 att nyinstallera, 0 att ta bort och 6 att inte uppgradera.
Behöver hämta 53,9 kB arkiv.
Efter denna åtgärd kommer ytterligare 273 kB utrymme användas på disken.
Vill du fortsätta? [J/n] j
Läs:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 oracle-java8-installer all 8u181-1~webupd8~1 [32,9 kB]
Läs:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 oracle-java8-set-default all 8u181-1~webupd8~1 [6 924 B]
Läs:3 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 java-common all 0.63ubuntu1~02 [7 032 B]
Läs:4 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/universe amd64 gsfonts-x11 all 0.26 [7 140 B]
Hämtade 53,9 kB på 1s (61,4 kB/s)           
Förkonfigurerar paket ...
Väljer tidigare ej valt paket java-common.
(Läser databasen ... 144678 filer och kataloger installerade.)
Förbereder att packa upp .../java-common_0.63ubuntu1~02_all.deb ...
Packar upp java-common (0.63ubuntu1~02) ...
Väljer tidigare ej valt paket oracle-java8-installer.
Förbereder att packa upp .../oracle-java8-installer_8u181-1~webupd8~1_all.deb ...
Packar upp oracle-java8-installer (8u181-1~webupd8~1) ...
Ställer in java-common (0.63ubuntu1~02) ...
Ställer in oracle-java8-installer (8u181-1~webupd8~1) ...
No /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/wgetrc file found.
Creating /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/wgetrc and
using default oracle-java8-installer wgetrc settings for it.
Downloading Oracle Java 8...
--2018-08-01 20:00:22--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u181-b13/96a7b8442fe848ef90c96a2fad6ed6d1/jdk-8u181-linux-x64.tar.gz
Slår upp download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 2.22.42.155
Ansluter till download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|2.22.42.155|:80... ansluten.
HTTP-begäran skickad, väntar på svar... 302 Moved Temporarily
Adress: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u181-b13/96a7b8442fe848ef90c96a2fad6ed6d1/jdk-8u181-linux-x64.tar.gz [följer]
--2018-08-01 20:00:23--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u181-b13/96a7b8442fe848ef90c96a2fad6ed6d1/jdk-8u181-linux-x64.tar.gz
Slår upp edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 23.13.247.92, 2a02:26f0:e2:18d::2d3e, 2a02:26f0:e2:1a2::2d3e
Ansluter till edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|23.13.247.92|:443... ansluten.
HTTP-begäran skickad, väntar på svar... 302 Moved Temporarily
Adress: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u181-b13/96a7b8442fe848ef90c96a2fad6ed6d1/jdk-8u181-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1533146543_14ec6f6c45be3cb100c0da89821b0218 [följer]
--2018-08-01 20:00:23--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u181-b13/96a7b8442fe848ef90c96a2fad6ed6d1/jdk-8u181-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1533146543_14ec6f6c45be3cb100c0da89821b0218
Ansluter till download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|2.22.42.155|:80... ansluten.
HTTP-begäran skickad, väntar på svar... 200 OK
Längd: 185646832 (177M) [application/x-gzip]
Sparar till: "jdk-8u181-linux-x64.tar.gz"

     0K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........  1% 8,62M 20s
  3072K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........  3% 9,85M 19s
  6144K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........  5% 9,60M 18s
  9216K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........  6% 10,5M 17s
 12288K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........  8% 11,2M 16s
 15360K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 10% 7,91M 17s
 18432K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 11% 9,61M 16s
 21504K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 13% 11,1M 16s
 24576K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 15% 10,9M 15s
 27648K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 16% 7,73M 15s
 30720K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 18% 10,8M 15s
 33792K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 20% 11,2M 14s
 36864K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 22% 9,05M 14s
 39936K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 23% 9,93M 14s
 43008K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 25% 11,2M 13s
 46080K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 27% 7,86M 13s
 49152K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 28% 8,94M 13s
 52224K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 30% 10,9M 13s
 55296K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 32% 4,49M 13s
 58368K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 33% 11,2M 13s
 61440K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 35% 11,1M 12s
 64512K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 37% 8,60M 12s
 67584K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 38% 10,7M 12s
 70656K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 40% 7,75M 11s
 73728K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 42% 8,63M 11s
 76800K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 44% 10,8M 11s
 79872K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 45% 10,9M 10s
 82944K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 47% 8,34M 10s
 86016K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 49% 10,1M 10s
 89088K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 50% 11,2M 9s
 92160K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 52% 9,89M 9s
 95232K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 54% 9,10M 9s
 98304K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 55% 11,0M 8s
101376K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 57% 9,49M 8s
104448K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 59% 9,54M 8s
107520K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 61% 10,5M 7s
110592K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 62% 11,2M 7s
113664K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 64% 9,35M 7s
116736K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 66% 9,65M 6s
119808K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 67% 11,2M 6s
122880K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 69% 10,8M 6s
125952K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 71% 8,66M 5s
129024K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 72% 10,9M 5s
132096K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 74% 11,2M 5s
135168K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 76% 8,93M 4s
138240K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 77% 10,1M 4s
141312K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 79% 3,56M 4s
144384K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 81% 4,61M 4s
147456K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 83% 11,0M 3s
150528K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 84% 11,2M 3s
153600K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 86% 8,70M 3s
156672K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 88% 10,3M 2s
159744K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 89% 11,2M 2s
162816K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 91% 9,58M 2s
165888K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 93% 9,42M 1s
168960K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 94% 11,1M 1s
172032K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 96% 10,7M 1s
175104K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 98% 8,82M 0s
178176K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 99% 10,7M 0s
181248K                                                      100% 11,1M=19s

2018-08-01 20:00:42 (9,24 MB/s) - "jdk-8u181-linux-x64.tar.gz" sparades [185646832/185646832]

Download done.
Removing outdated cached downloads...
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for java
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/ControlPanel för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/ControlPanel (ControlPanel) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/java (java) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/javaws för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/javaws (javaws) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/jcontrol för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/jcontrol (jcontrol) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/jjs för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/jjs (jjs) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/keytool för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/keytool (keytool) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/orbd för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/orbd (orbd) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/pack200 för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/pack200 (pack200) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/policytool för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/policytool (policytool) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/rmid för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/rmid (rmid) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/rmiregistry för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/rmiregistry (rmiregistry) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/servertool för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/servertool (servertool) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/tnameserv för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/tnameserv (tnameserv) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/unpack200 för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/unpack200 (unpack200) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jexec för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/jexec (jexec) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/appletviewer för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/appletviewer (appletviewer) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/extcheck för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/extcheck (extcheck) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/idlj för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/idlj (idlj) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jar för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/jar (jar) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jarsigner för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/jarsigner (jarsigner) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javac för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/javac (javac) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javadoc för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/javadoc (javadoc) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javafxpackager för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/javafxpackager (javafxpackager) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javah för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/javah (javah) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javap för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/javap (javap) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javapackager för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/javapackager (javapackager) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jcmd för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/jcmd (jcmd) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jconsole för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/jconsole (jconsole) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jdb för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/jdb (jdb) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jdeps för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/jdeps (jdeps) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jhat för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/jhat (jhat) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jinfo för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/jinfo (jinfo) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jmap för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/jmap (jmap) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jmc för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/jmc (jmc) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jps för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/jps (jps) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jrunscript för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/jrunscript (jrunscript) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jsadebugd för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/jsadebugd (jsadebugd) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jstack för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/jstack (jstack) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jstat för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/jstat (jstat) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jstatd för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/jstatd (jstatd) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jvisualvm för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/jvisualvm (jvisualvm) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/native2ascii för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/native2ascii (native2ascii) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/rmic för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/rmic (rmic) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/schemagen för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/schemagen (schemagen) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/serialver för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/serialver (serialver) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/wsgen för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/wsgen (wsgen) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/wsimport för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/wsimport (wsimport) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/xjc för att tillhandahålla /usr/bin/xjc (xjc) i autoläge
update-alternatives: använder /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so för att tillhandahålla /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin.so (mozilla-javaplugin.so) i autoläge
Oracle JDK 8 installed

#####Important########
To set Oracle JDK8 as default, install the "oracle-java8-set-default" package.
E.g.: sudo apt install oracle-java8-set-default
On Ubuntu systems, oracle-java8-set-default is most probably installed
automatically with this package.
######################

Väljer tidigare ej valt paket oracle-java8-set-default.
(Läser databasen ... 144714 filer och kataloger installerade.)
Förbereder att packa upp .../oracle-java8-set-default_8u181-1~webupd8~1_all.deb ...
Packar upp oracle-java8-set-default (8u181-1~webupd8~1) ...
Väljer tidigare ej valt paket gsfonts-x11.
Förbereder att packa upp .../gsfonts-x11_0.26_all.deb ...
Packar upp gsfonts-x11 (0.26) ...
Ställer in gsfonts-x11 (0.26) ...
Hanterar utlösare för mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Hanterar utlösare för desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu4) ...
Ställer in oracle-java8-set-default (8u181-1~webupd8~1) ...
Hanterar utlösare för man-db (2.8.4-2) ...
Hanterar utlösare för shared-mime-info (1.9-2) ...
Hanterar utlösare för gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu2) ...
Hanterar utlösare för hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Hanterar utlösare för fontconfig (2.12.6-0ubuntu2) ...
$
```